# Java How do I get all map values within specific keys?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, key, double

right now I have a `Map` like this:

```
Map<Double, MyObject> map = new HashMap<Double, MyObject>();
```

I want to get all values of keys that are between `2.0` and `7.0`. I have thousands of different values in my `Map`, so looping through every `key-value` set will be heavy for performance. Is there any way to solve this? (Or is there some sort of special map, that is used to have number keys?) Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Take a look at [TreeMaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). They allow you to create submaps based on the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead. Through its [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface, you can perform range operations.

```
NavigableMap<Double, MyObject> map = new TreeMap<>();
Collection<MyObject> keys = map.subMap(2D, 7D).values();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this is what I need! But is there a way to have more than one value in the keys (like String that follows pattern: Double,Double)?

Comment: Yes, you could define your own class for the key. To use it with a `TreeMap`, you need to define an order, and have your key class implement the `Comparable` interface. (Alternatively, you can express the order in a `Comparator` object.)

Comment: Technically, `subMap(K, K)` is available through the `SortedMap` interface.